# Mark the "current day" on the calendar

Tags: calendar

i use overlead and now i want to highlight current date on month calendar.
This guide: [Calendar with TIKZ-PGF: How to highlight current date?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387240/calendar-with-tikz-pgf-how-to-highlight-current-date).
But in my calendar display wrong place (Please see image)
Thanks
[image]
My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
%pagesize,
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
%\usepackage{libertine} % fonts not installed here
\usepackage{translator, tikz, array} % pgfcalendar loaded later with \usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{xcolor} % loaded by tikz
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{color} % unnecessary, because xcolor already loaded
%\usepackage{pgf} % loaded by tikz

%=========================================================
%== Page characteristics (Page Setup) ====================
% using geometry would be better


\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%== Define colors =================================
\definecolor{rozmam}{RGB}{242,172,184}
\newcommand{\troz}{\textcolor{rozmam}}


\makeatletter%
% these days, \tikzset is used
\tikzset{%
    day headings/.style={day heading=#1}, % \tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
    day heading/.style={}, % \tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
    day letter headings/.style={% \tikzstyle{day letter headings} ...
        execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
          \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
          \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
          \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
          \foreach \d/\l in {0/M,1/T,2/W,3/T,4/F,5/S,6/S} {
            \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
            \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
            \node[every day,day heading]{\l};%
          }
        }{}%
      }
    }
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}


\foreach \n in {2,...,2}{

\pgfcalendar{cal}{2018-\n-01}{2018-\n-last}
{
% added to ensure every day starts on a new page
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
% remember day and month

\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\captionsetup{skip=4pt, minmargin=0cm, maxmargin=0cm}
{
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Image/ABC.jpg}
 \captionof*{figure}{\textcolor{red}{ABC}}
}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{0.8cm} 
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\centering
\Huge  \textcolor{blue}{Planner} \\

\edef\pagedayofmonth{\pgfcalendarcurrentday}%
\edef\pagemonth{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}%
\noindent
{
\Huge \pgfcalendarweekdayname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}
\Huge \bfseries
\pgfcalendarcurrentday{}\\[20pt]

}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, transform shape]
  \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=8pt, xshift = -15pt]
    at (current page.north east)
    {
      \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {anchor=center}]
        \calendar (mycal) [dates=2018-\n-01 to 2018-\n-last,
        week list,
        day text=\%d0,
        month label above centered,
        month text={\%mt} \%y-,
        day xshift = 0.8cm,
        day headings=gray,
        day letter headings
    ]
    if (Saturday) [rozmam]
    if (Sunday)   [rozmam]
    % just set another text color; nodes={draw} could be added, but the rectangle is too large
    if (day of month=\pagedayofmonth) [cyan]
    ;
    % draw a frame around the day
    \draw[green,thick,rounded corners]
        ($(mycal-2018-\pagemonth-\pagedayofmonth.south east) + (-1.5mm,1.5mm)$) rectangle 
        ($(mycal-2018-\pagemonth-\pagedayofmonth.north west) + (1.5mm,-1.5mm)$);


      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\\[30pt]
\pagebreak
%{}
 }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code produces multiple errors.

Comment: i complete in overleaf and it can ignore some errors

Comment: Though overleaf can ignore errors (as well as any other TeX installation), it might be the source of the issues. It is never a good idea to let errors pile up.

Comment: Thanks Skillmon, but i can not fix these errors

Comment: I just noticed that you did use `<pre>...</pre>` to mark the code in your question. That is the wrong way and leads to the wrong output, which I copied, inserting multiple syntax errors which weren't there in your code. To mark displayed code as such, either select it with your mouse and hit the `{}` button in the editor, or indent each line by four spaces (which is what the code button does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code *compiled thrice* does produce correct output (I just removed a superfluous `\\` and changed the `\edef\pagedayofmonth` and `\edef\pagemonth` to `\xdef\pagedayofmonth` and `\xdef\pagemonth`, and replaced your image with one generally available on TeX Live and MikTeX).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
%pagesize,
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[romanian]{babel}
%\usepackage{libertine} % fonts not installed here
\usepackage{translator, tikz, array} % pgfcalendar loaded later with \usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{xcolor} % loaded by tikz
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{color} % unnecessary, because xcolor already loaded
%\usepackage{pgf} % loaded by tikz

%=========================================================
%== Page characteristics (Page Setup) ====================
% using geometry would be better


\usetikzlibrary{calendar,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%== Define colors =================================
\definecolor{rozmam}{RGB}{242,172,184}
\newcommand{\troz}{\textcolor{rozmam}}


\makeatletter%
% these days, \tikzset is used
\tikzset{%
    day headings/.style={day heading=#1}, % \tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
    day heading/.style={}, % \tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
    day letter headings/.style={% \tikzstyle{day letter headings} ...
        execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
          \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
          \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
          \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}
          \foreach \d/\l in {0/M,1/T,2/W,3/T,4/F,5/S,6/S} {
            \pgf@xa=\d\pgf@xa%
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}%
            \pgftransformyshift{\pgf@ya}%
            \node[every day,day heading]{\l};%
          }
        }{}%
      }
    }
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}


\foreach \n in {2,...,2}{

\pgfcalendar{cal}{2018-\n-01}{2018-\n-last}
{
% added to ensure every day starts on a new page
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
% remember day and month

\begin{minipage}{3cm}
\captionsetup{skip=4pt, minmargin=0cm, maxmargin=0cm}
{
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck}
 \captionof*{figure}{\textcolor{red}{ABC}}
}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{0.8cm} 
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
\centering
\Huge  \textcolor{blue}{Planner} \\

\xdef\pagedayofmonth{\pgfcalendarcurrentday}%
\xdef\pagemonth{\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth}%
\noindent
{
\Huge \pgfcalendarweekdayname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday}
\Huge \bfseries
\pgfcalendarcurrentday{}\\[20pt]

}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, transform shape]
  \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=8pt, xshift = -15pt]
    at (current page.north east)
    {
      \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {anchor=center}]
        \calendar (mycal) [dates=2018-\n-01 to 2018-\n-last,
        week list,
        day text=\%d0,
        month label above centered,
        month text={\%mt} \%y-,
        day xshift = 0.8cm,
        day headings=gray,
        day letter headings
    ]
    if (Saturday) [rozmam]
    if (Sunday)   [rozmam]
    % just set another text color; nodes={draw} could be added, but the rectangle is too large
    if (day of month=\pagedayofmonth) [cyan]
    ;
    % draw a frame around the day
    \draw[green,thick,rounded corners]
        ($(mycal-2018-\pagemonth-\pagedayofmonth.south east) + (-1.5mm,1.5mm)$) rectangle 
        ($(mycal-2018-\pagemonth-\pagedayofmonth.north west) + (1.5mm,-1.5mm)$);


      \end{tikzpicture}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\pagebreak
%{}
 }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank Skillmon, your code is really better.

Comment: @BVOT it isn't my code, I just changed three lines...

Comment: i change the number of year 2018 -> 2019 then this error again: highlight position not in current day. "\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style = {anchor=center}]
        \calendar (mycal) [dates=2019-\n-01 to 2019-\n-last," can you fix it? Thanks

Comment: @tisaigon if I change every occurrence of `2018` with `2019` I don't get any errors and it builds fine.

Comment: Thank skillmon, how can i move this calendar x to left postion (1cm) and y to below position (1cm)

Comment: @tisaigon your initial question is answered. Please don't expand the question further by asking more stuff in the comments. Instead you can ask a follow up question (open a new thread including a link to this one) on how to move the output around. Maybe the `xshift` and `yshift` option applied to your `tikzpicture` could help.