# Get the first day of the week and the weekend

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, calendar, datetime2

I am working on a weekly teaching plan. I need the start date and end date of each week. For example, week 30 I want 7/25 - 7/29, week 31 I want 1/8 - 5/8. I don't want to do this manually, because it takes a long time. Is there a convenient way to get the first and last day of a week? Thank you.[image]

Comment: If you know Python there's always the option of using e.g. `pythontex` and its datetime module

Comment: Maybe look for termcal/datetime2 package

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know python.

Comment: I suggest checking in PGF manual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf  *Section 47 Calendar Library* for the `calendar` library of TikZ, and *Section 89 Date and Calendar Utility Macros* for the package `pgfcalendar`. This package can be used independently of pgf.

Comment: Thank you, I will read it.

Comment: You can create the table with any spreadsheet program and export it to LaTeX.
Only the numerical data of the first line are to be fixed, the other lines are deduced from it by fairly elementary operations.

Answer (score 1):

## Specifying the first day of the first week manually

You can use `pgfcalendar` to store the first day of your first week in a LaTeX counter and use that later as the base for an offset.

With `\setStartDate` you set the first day of your first week and the `\getDateOfWeek{<week>}{<offset>}` will define `\Year`, `\Month`, `\Day` with the date that is in the `<week>`th week with an additional `<offset>`.

For example:

```
\setStartDate{2022-10-10}
```

sets the first week to start on October 10th, 2022.

With

```
\getDateOfWeek{1}{4}
```

you'll get October 14th and with

```
\getDateOfWeek{2}{0}
```

you'll get October 17th in `\Month` and `\Day`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\newcounter{myStartDate}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\setStartDate}[1]{% for week 1
  \begingroup
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\@tempcnta}%
    \setcounter{myStartDate}{\@tempcnta}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\getDateOfWeek}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \@tempcnta=\inteval{(#1-1)*7+#2}\relax
    \advance\@tempcnta by \c@myStartDate
    \edef\@temp{\endgroup\noexpand\pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\the\@tempcnta}}%
    \@temp{\Year}{\Month}{\Day}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\setStartDate{2022-01-03}
\foreach \week in {1,...,52}{
  Week \week\ goes from \getDateOfWeek{\week}{0}\Month/\Day\ to
                        \getDateOfWeek{\week}{4}\Month/\Day.\par}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Using the actual week numbers of the years.

With the `pgfcalendar-ext` package of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) which incorporates [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651888/16595) and uses the week numbering according to ISO 8601 which mainly means that a new week starts on Monday.

Here's a solution with

```
\getTwoDaysOfWeek[<year>]{<week>}{<offset>}
  {<year>}{<month>}{<day>}{<offset year>}{<offset month>}{<offset day>}
```

which defines six macros (the argments on the second line) for you which contain

- the first day of `<week>` of `<year>` and
- the day that's `<offset>` after the first day of `<week>` of `<year>`.

The `<year>` argument is optionally, the default is the current year.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar-ext}
\newcommand*{\stripZero}[1]{\if0#1\else#1\fi}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\getTwoDaysOfWeek}[9][\the\year]{%
  % #1 = year (defaults to current year)
  % #2 = week number, #3 = offset
  % #4/#5/#6 = start year/month/day
  % #7/#8/#9 = end year/month/day
  \begingroup
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1-01-01}{\@tempcnta}%
    \pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\@tempcnta}{\@tempcntb}%
    \edef\@dateStartWeek{\the\numexpr\@tempcnta-\@tempcntb+#2*7-7\relax}%
    \pgfcalendarjulianyeartoweek{\@tempcnta}{#1}{\@tempcntb}%
    \ifnum\@tempcntb>1
      % This is the last week of the previous year
      \edef\@dateStartWeek{\the\numexpr\@dateStartWeek+7\relax}%
    \fi
    \edef\@temp{\endgroup%
      \noexpand\pgfcalendarjuliantodate
        {\@dateStartWeek}{\noexpand#4}{\noexpand#5}{\noexpand#6}%
      \noexpand\pgfcalendarjuliantodate
        {\the\numexpr\@dateStartWeek+#3\relax}{\noexpand#7}{\noexpand#8}{\noexpand#9}}%
  \@temp
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\weekCell}[2][\the\year]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Week #2:\\
    \getTwoDaysOfWeek[#1]{#2}{4}{\y}{\m}{\d}{\Y}{\M}{\D}%
    \stripZero\m/\stripZero\d--\stripZero\M/\stripZero\D
  \end{tabular}}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Time & Content & Note \\\midrule
\weekCell{1} & Content 1 & Note 1 \\
\weekCell{2} & Content 2 & Note 2 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Qrrbrbirlbel, thank you so much.