# How to loop calendar files for my filofax organizer

Tags: loops, calendar

Sometime ago I've found a really nice snippet for creating Filofax (tm) organizer A5 calendar pages -- sadly I could not find the original source anymore. Subsequently I've modified it and now I'm looking forward to use it.

However, I couldn't manage to create more then two consistent pages. It would be really nice if I could add a loop so that I could create more then one week at the time. Maybe a month, a year, or even a arbitrary time span.

```
\documentclass[%
a5paper,
BCOR=2cm,%  Space for hole puncher
DIV=25,%    Size of textbody
9pt%       Fontsize
]{scrbook}
%
%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%
%
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,multirow}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{roboto}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%
%%%%%%%%%% COUNTER %%%%%%%%%%
%
\newcount\counter
\newcount\startdate
\newcount\starttime
\newcount\stoptime
\newcount\sundaybegin
\newcount\week
%
%%%%%%%%%% CUSTOMISATIONS %%%%%%%%%%
%
%% Month
\renewcommand{\month}{March}
%% Date to start the week with
\startdate=13
%% Morning starttime
\starttime=8
%% Evening time
\stoptime=20
%% Starttime sunday
% Min \starttime+1
% Max \stoptime-2
\sundaybegin=14
%% Weeknumber
\week=11
%% Rule width thick
\newcommand{\rulew}{.15em}
%% Extra space
%\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
%
%%%%%%%%%% DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%%
%
\newcommand{\lendt}{\cmidrule[\rulew](l){1-2}\cmidrule[\rulew](l){3-4}\cmidrule[\rulew](l){5-6}}
\newcommand{\lend}{\cmidrule(l){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}}
\newcommand{\lsun}{\cmidrule(l){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}}
\newcommand{\lsunt}{\cmidrule(l){1-2}\cmidrule(l){3-4}\cmidrule[\rulew](l){5-6}}
\newcommand{\printday}[2]{{\LARGE \textbf{#1}}\,\, \large \textbf{#2}}
\newcommand{\neutralline}{& & & & &}
\newcommand{\footer}{\centering\rule{5.5cm}{\cmidrulewidth} \raisebox{-0.5ex}{\textbf{Dragosh Christian OTTO}} \rule{5.5cm}{\cmidrulewidth}}
\newcommand{\printmonth}{{\LARGE \textbf{\month}}}
%
%%%%%%%%%% TABLE CONTENT LEFT SIDE %%%%%%%%%%
%
% Correction due to \global\advance
\advance\startdate-6
%
\advance\stoptime1
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
%
\def\tabledataleft{} \counter=\the\starttime
\loop
    \edef\tabline{\the\counter & & \the\counter & & \the\counter & }
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledataleft\expandafter{\tabline \\\lend}    
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledataleft\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledataleft\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledataleft\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \advance \counter 2
    \ifnum \counter<\the\stoptime
\repeat 
%
%%%%%%%%%% TABLE CONTENT RIGHT SIDE %%%%%%%%%%
%
\def\tabledatarightupper{} \counter=\the\starttime
\loop
    \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & & }
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightupper\expandafter{\tabline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightupper\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightupper\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightupper\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \advance \counter 2
    \ifnum \counter<\the\sundaybegin
\repeat 
%
\advance\sundaybegin1
\def\tabledatarightinter{} \counter=\the\sundaybegin
\newcount\sundaystop
\sundaystop=\the\sundaybegin
\advance\sundaystop1
\loop
    \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & & }
    %\expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightinter\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lsun}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightinter\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lsun}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightinter\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lsun}
    \advance \counter 2
    \ifnum \counter<\the\sundaystop
\repeat
\advance\sundaybegin-1
\advance\sundaystop1
%
\def\tabledatarightlower{} \counter=\the\sundaystop
\loop
    \advance \counter 1
    \edef\tabline{\the\counter &  & \the\counter & & & }
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightlower\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightlower\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightlower\expandafter{\neutralline \\\lend}
    \expandafter\addto\expandafter\tabledatarightlower\expandafter{\tabline \\\lend}
    \advance \counter 1
    \ifnum \counter<\the\stoptime
\repeat 
\advance\sundaystop-1
%
\begin{document}
%
%% Empty page to start left
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\clearpage
%
\pagestyle{empty}
\enlargethispage{1cm}
%
%%%%%%%%%% LEFT TABLE %%%%%%%%%%
%
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlXlX}
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\printmonth \hfill Week \the\week}\\[.2em]
    \midrule[\rulew]
    \addlinespace[.5em]
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Monday}} \global\advance\startdate 1\relax &%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Tuesday}} \global\advance\startdate 1\relax &%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Wednesday}}\global\advance\startdate 1\relax \\[1cm]
     & & & & & \\\lendt
    \tabledataleft
     & & & & & \\[1cm]
     \midrule[\rulew]
\end{tabularx}
%
\vfill
%\footer
%
\clearpage
\enlargethispage{1cm}
% Correction due to \global\advance
\advance\startdate-6
%
%%%%%%%%%% RIGHT TABLE %%%%%%%%%%
%
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlXlX}
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{Week \the\week \hfill \printmonth}\\[.2em]\midrule[\rulew]
    \addlinespace[.5em]
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Thursday}} \global\advance\startdate 1\relax &%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Friday}}   \global\advance\startdate 1\relax &%
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\printday{\the\startdate}{Saturday}} \global\advance\startdate 1\relax \\[1cm]
    & & & & & \\\lendt
    \tabledatarightupper
    %& & & & & \\\lsunt
    \addlinespace[-.15em]
    \the\sundaybegin & & \the\sundaybegin & & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\multirow{4}{*}[1.5em]{\printday{\the\startdate}{Sunday}}}\\\lsun
    \tabledatarightinter
    & & & & & \\\lsun
    \the\sundaystop & & \the\sundaystop & & & \\\lsunt
    \tabledatarightlower
    & & & & & \\\lend
    & & & & & \\\lend
    & & & & & \\\lend
    & & & & & \\[1cm]
    \midrule[\rulew]
\end{tabularx}
%
\vfill
%\footer
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PGF/TikZ comes with the “utility” [PGFCalendar](https://tikz.dev/pgfcalendar).
With my `tikz-ext` package I have added [support for week numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651888/16595).
For this, you will actually need to load the `pgfcalendar-ext` package.

Now, PGFCalendar has one main command: [`\pgfcalendar`](https://tikz.dev/pgfcalendar#%5Cpgfcalendar)

It does loop through all dates specificed in the range and sets up a few macros (and one TeX count) that holds information about the current day. (And `pgfcalendar-ext` extends that so that the weeknumber is also available.)

Now, we don't want to actually loop through every single date but only want to look at Mondays (left side) and at Thursday (right side).

So at the last, we trick PGFCalendar by time-travelling to Wednesday (left side) and Sunday (right side):

```
\ifdate{Monday}{\advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by 2}
               {\advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by 3}
\clearpage
```

We could actually just use `\ifodd\value{page}` to figure out where we are but here I'm using PGFCalendar's `\ifdate` where Monday indicates the left side.

Since the head and the foot of each page is roughly the same we typeset this directly in the loop. We use the same test to figure out if we have to typeset the left or the right header setup. (We probably could have used the left and right mark of the Koma classes for this but that's not our main concern here.)

After we typeset the three days on the top (more on that later) we again have to think about on which page we are (→ `\ifdate{Monday}`).

For the left side we just typeset all rows for all the times.
For the right side we have to break it up for the Sunday.

Instead of your pre-built templates , I'm using Latex3's `\int_step_function:nnnN` as simple for(each) loop. It can be safely used inside a `tabularx`.
The Sunday side is a bit messy. I've made a few adjustments:

- Take a look at `\lineEndSundayTop` where I've added a linespace that will make the table ignore the extra thickness of `\ruleThick` so that the grid of lines on the right side is spaced exactly the same as on the left side.
- The Sunday header is lowered (negatively raised) while being `\smash`ed so that it doesn't snuck up to the upper line without enlarging the line vertically.

---

Now, we can't simply add one, two or – for the Sunday – three to the current day to get the other days on the page that aren't Monday or Thursday because each one of these days could be in the next month.

We could check around a bit if we would be above 28/29/30/31 and adjust things accordingly but I will just let PGFCalendar do that job again via `\PGFCalendarPlus`.

This macro will start another `\pgfcalendar` loop of one (1) day, the one that is one, two or days after the current one (which is either a Monday or a Thursday). We'll print the day number and weekday and that's it.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a5paper, BCOR=2cm, DIV=25, fontsize=9pt]{scrbook}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651888
\usepackage{pgfcalendar-ext} % loads pgfcalendar and has weeknumbering
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{xfp}% for \inteval for older TeX distributions
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% horizontal lines in tabularx
\newcommand*\lineEndTop      {\cmidrule[\ruleThick](l){1-2}\cmidrule[\ruleThick](l){3-4}\cmidrule[\ruleThick](l){5-6}}
\newcommand*\lineEnd         {\cmidrule            (l){1-2}\cmidrule            (l){3-4}\cmidrule            (l){5-6}}
\newcommand*\lineEndSunday   {\cmidrule            (l){1-2}\cmidrule            (l){3-4}}
\newcommand*\lineEndSundayTop{\cmidrule            (l){1-2}\cmidrule            (l){3-4}\cmidrule[\ruleThick](l){5-6}%
                              \addlinespace[\dimexpr-\ruleThick+\lightrulewidth]}
\newcommand*\printDay        {{\LARGE \textbf{\%d-}}\,\, \large \textbf{\%wt}}
\newcommand*\printDays       {%
  \multicolumn{2}{l}                    {\printDay}  &
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\PGFcalendarPlus{1}{\printDay}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l}{\PGFcalendarPlus{2}{\printDay}}}
\newcommand*\printWeekLeft   {{\bfseries\LARGE\%mt} \hfill Week \%n-}
\newcommand*\printWeekRight  {Week \%n-\hfill {\bfseries\LARGE\%mt}}
\newcommand*\timeStart  {8}
\newcommand*\timeEnd   {20}
\newcommand*\timeStep   {2}
\newcommand*\timeSunday{14}
\newcommand*\timeBlockX[2]{%
  #1 & & #1 & & #2 \\ \lineEnd
  & & & & &        \\ \lineEnd \\ \lineEnd \\ \lineEnd}
\newcommand*\timeBlockLeft [1]{\timeBlockX{#1}{#1}}
\newcommand*\timeBlockRight[1]{\timeBlockX{#1}{}}
\newcommand*\blockSunday[3]{% Ugh!
  \inteval{\timeSunday-\timeStep} & &
  \inteval{\timeSunday-\timeStep} & & \\ \lineEnd
  \\ \lineEnd       \\ \lineEnd       \\ \lineEndSundayTop
  \timeSunday & & \timeSunday & & #1  \\ \lineEndSunday
  \\ \lineEndSunday \\ \lineEndSunday}

\newcommand*\PGFcalendarPlus[2]{%
  \pgfcalendar{temp}{\pgfcalendarcurrentyear-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentday+#1}
                    {\pgfcalendarcurrentyear-\pgfcalendarcurrentmonth-\pgfcalendarcurrentday+#1}{#2}}

\newcommand*\ruleThick{.15em}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}% instead of \noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn \let\FOREACH\int_step_function:nnnN \ExplSyntaxOff
\let\%\pgfcalendarshorthand
%\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\null\clearpage
\pgfcalendar{cal}{2023-03-13}{2023-06-30}{%
  \enlargethispage{1cm}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXlXlX}
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\ifdate{Monday}{\printWeekLeft}{\printWeekRight}}\\[.2em]
    \midrule[\ruleThick] \addlinespace[.5em]
    \printDays \\[4em]\lineEndTop
  \ifdate{Monday}{% left page
    \FOREACH{\timeStart}{\timeStep}{\timeEnd}\timeBlockLeft
  }{%
    \FOREACH{\timeStart}{\timeStep}{\inteval{\timeSunday-2*\timeStep}}\timeBlockRight
    \blockSunday{\multicolumn{2}{l}{\PGFcalendarPlus{3}{\smash{\raisebox{-.3em}{\printDay}}}}}{}{}
    \\\lineEndSundayTop
    \FOREACH{\inteval{\timeSunday+\timeStep}}{\timeStep}{\timeEnd}\timeBlockRight
  }%
    \\[1cm]
    \midrule[\ruleThick]
  \end{tabularx}
  \ifdate{Monday}{\advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by 2}
                 {\advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by 3}
  \clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[It's a video.](https://i.imgur.com/UENAlkr.mp4)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirbel: First of all: Wow! And thank you for your work. It looks really nice, like the detailed explanation. Sadly I cannot reproduce it because the compiler (`LuaLaTeX`) can't find `pgfcalendar-ext.sty`. The links 1 and 2 on the [suggested linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517338/add-week-day-to-calendar/651888#651888) are dead. You suggest that `\ifodd\value{page}` could be also used. Is it possible to offer also an solution with the standard `texlive-full` packages?

Comment: @alex [`tikz-ext`](https://ctan.prg/pkg/tikz-ext), which provides `pgfcalendar-ext.sty`, is a quite new package (first release AFAIK 2022). Since TeX Live packages from Linux distributions are often rather older, I would be surprised if `tikz-ext` would be offered via the Linux package manager. In Vanilla TeX Live, however, it is included since 2022 and installable via `tlmgr`. As a last resort, you could install it from [CTAN](https://ctan.prg/pkg/tikz-ext).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirbel: as suggested, by @cabohah, I've installed the package manually from [CTAN `tkiz-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext). The package documentation doesn't describe the installation process so I've used [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993965/include-sty-file-from-a-super-subdirectory-of-main-tex-file). Now there seems to be some bracketting [error](https://collabedit.com/p88py). I've searched for 15m now and did not find any. If possible, please add an alternative version with `\ifodd\value{page}`. It could be important to other, unexperienced users (me), to test it.

Comment: @alex The linked error messages seem to be only a snippet. They are not the complete log file. So I even cannot say, where the error happens. Off-Topic: You should replace the deprecated option `9pt` by `fontsize=9pt`.

Comment: @alex You could use a LaTeX counter `\newcounter{weeknumber}` for the week number which you have to manually set for the first week `\setcounter{weeknumber}{11}` and then increment it at the end of the week: `\ifdate{Monday}{\advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by 2}{\stepcounter{weeknumber}\advance\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian by 3}`.

Comment: @alex I think these [installation guides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/16595) are better. But you can also just put [`pgfcalendar-ext.sty`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/tikz-extensions/blob/main/tex/latex/tikz-ext/pgfcalendar-ext.sty) and [`pgfcalendar-ext.code.tex`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/tikz-extensions/blob/main/tex/generic/tikz-ext/pgfcalendar-ext.code.tex) in the same folder as your main `.tex` file. The compiler should find them then.

Comment: @alex Since your Linux provided TeX Live installation doesn't get updates you will need to `\usepackage{xfp}` for `\inteval`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thank you! It workes. Maybe it could be usefull to add the package `xfp` into the code with a specific comment for when this is required. Best whishes!